# No inglês, o conceito de "living wage" é diferente de "minimum wage". Existe algum equivalente para "living wage" em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, vocabulário

A expressão "salário mínimo" é comum no português, mas ela se refere ao valor mínimo estabelecido por lei.

Existe alguma expressão similar à expressão "living wage", que se refere ao valor mínimo para ser viver uma vida digna baseado no custo de vida médio da região?

Comment: Pode estar relacionado: [salário mínimo necessário](https://www.dieese.org.br/metodologia/metodologiaCestaBasica2016.pdf). Mas ainda é algo muito abrangente, já que, pelo menos nessa referência, diz ser para o Brasil inteiro, enquanto o _living wage_ teria grandes variações de acordo com cidades e estados. Parece também que esse indicador é só em relação à alimentação (de uma família). Achei outros lugares chamando o _salário mínimo necessário_ de _salário mínimo ideal_.

Comment: Achado interessante, @RafaelTavares, mas eu diria que se resumir às necessidades alimentares, como se entende do texto, realmente é um problema para essa ser a melhor tradução.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Me enganei. Lendo devidamente o documento que você menciona, vê-se que, apesar do cálculo ser de fato baseado na cesta básica, ela é apenas a referência base e o "salário mínimo necessário" como o salário que "deve atender as necessidades básicas do trabalhador e de sua família" [na capital mais cara do país]. Vou atualizar a resposta. Obrigado pelo achado!

Answer (score 11):

Sim, há equivalente — na verdade existe mais de uma tradução possível para "*living wage*".

**Resumo**: Uma boa opção é "salário de subsistência", outras incluem "salário mínimo necessário" e "salário mínimo ideal".

No contexto brasileiro, vale notar, antes de mais nada, que o salário mínimo como [definido na Constituição](https://www.senado.leg.br/atividade/const/con1988/con1988_05.10.1988/art_7_.asp) se trata na verdade do *living wage*<sup>[1]</sup>:

> **Art. 7º** São direitos dos trabalhadores urbanos e rurais [...]
> IV -  salário mínimo, fixado em lei, nacionalmente unificado, capaz de atender às suas necessidades vitais básicas e às de sua família com moradia, alimentação, educação, saúde, lazer, vestuário, higiene, transporte e previdência social, com reajustes periódicos que lhe preservem o poder aquisitivo

Que corresponde bem às definições usuais de [*living wage*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/living+wage):

> *n.* A wage sufficient to provide minimally satisfactory living conditions.
>
> *n.* (Economics) a wage adequate to permit a wage earner to live and support a family in reasonable comfort

Por esta razão, o valor do salário mínimo de fato estabelecido pelo governo é por vezes chamado de "salário mínimo nominal".

O termo utilizado pelo [Dieese](https://www.dieese.org.br/notatecnica/2019/notaTec218SalarioMinimo.html) para o salário que realmente atende à Constituição é "[**salário mínimo necessário**](https://www.dieese.org.br/analisecestabasica/salarioMinimo.html)". Como a constituição determina que ele seja "nacionalmente unificado", esse valor não considera variações regionais.

Ele é [calculado](https://www.dieese.org.br/metodologia/metodologiaCestaBasica2016.pdf) com base no custo da [cesta básica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesta_b%C3%A1sica) mais cara do país, considerando uma família de 4 pessoas que consome 3 cestas básicas, e cuja alimentação é responsável por 35,71% de suas despesas mensais. Esse valor do salário é também [chamado](https://www.cnnbrasil.com.br/business/salario-minimo-ideal-subiu-para-r-5351-11-em-maio-diz-dieese/) de "**salário mínimo ideal**".

Uma alternativa, talvez menos técnica, é "**salário de subsistência**". Essa é a tradução dada pelo [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-portuguese/living-wage), e foi usada, por exemplo, pela [Deutsche Welle](https://www.dw.com/pt-br/por-que-o-sal%C3%A1rio-m%C3%ADnimo-na-alemanha-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-t%C3%A3o-bom-quanto-parece/a-46931983):

> Uma razão para isso pode ser a chamada "Living Wage Campaign" ("Campanha pelo Salário de Subsistência", em tradução livre) no Reino Unido, que há anos vem influenciando a discussão sobre salários mínimos.

E o termo também aparece em trabalhos acadêmicos, por exemplo:

- no trabalho de conclusão de curso de Diego Fangueiro Vieira, [Determinação salarial na economia política clássica : uma leitura sraffiana](http://hdl.handle.net/11422/1280):

> Um salário de subsistência consiste naquele montante exatamente suficiente para permitir  a aquisição  dos  bens  necessários  para  o  sustento  do  trabalhador  e  sua  família.

- e no artigo [Salários: aspectos econômicos considerados para a sua determinação](https://periodicos.unichristus.edu.br/opiniaojuridica/article/view/1889) de da Silva e de Carvalho:

> salário de subsistência. O valor da cesta de bens necessários à manutenção do trabalhador e de sua família.

"Salário de subsistência" também é a possibilidade mais votada num [forúm de tradução](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english-to-portuguese/journalism/3196945-living-wage.html).

Neste mesmo fórum e algures também são sugeridos "salário digno/justo/decente/razoável", mas estes termos têm conotações mais informais e/ou subjetivas — similarmente para "salário condigno", a tradução dada pelo dicionário da [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-portuguese/living-wage).

Um conceito estreitamente relacionado ao salário de subsistência é o "custo de vida" — se poderia traduzir "*living wage*" como "salário adequado ao custo de vida". Mas vale notar que, além de significar "Nível de recursos necessários para atender às necessidades básicas" ([Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/custo), ver também [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/custo/)), o termo pode também denotar um índice de variação:  "índice da variação dos preços de bens e serviços consumidos por uma parte representativa da população" ([Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/index.php#2), ver também [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/custo?express=custo+de+vida)), sentido mais distante do *living wage*.

<sup>[1] Portanto um salário mínimo que não satisfaça essa exigência (e nenhum nunca satisfez) é a rigor inconstitucional.</sup>

Comment: Excelente resposta. Muito interessante a definição da própria Constituição.